# Additional text to labels in legend r

Tags: r, ggplot2, text, label

I am new to r and I wonder if there is a way to add some additional texts into the label of legend. For my case I want to add some additional `percentage` to each label text of the legend but I failed to achieve it. I try to use `scale_fill_hue` but it did not work.

Here is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

cv_states = read.csv("coronavirus_states.csv")
a <- cv_states %>%
  group_by(state) %>%
  summarise(total= sum(new_cases)) %>%
  mutate(pourcentage= total/sum(total)*100) 

  ggplot(a,aes(x=fct_reorder(state,pourcentage),y=pourcentage,fill=state))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width=5))+
  scale_color_hue( labels = paste0( as.factor(a$state) , ' (', round(as.numeric(a$pourcentage) ,digits = 2), "%)"))+
  coord_flip()
```

Here is my picture:
[image]

In addition to this, if I used `scale_fill_manual` I need to put the color 55 times by myself which is huge. My goal is just to let `ggplot2` fill the colors by its choice like I put `fill=state` in the `ggplot` function and I just want to add some texts of percentage like for example `New York (22%)` and the other states are the same.

In case you need a file test you can find here: https://gitlab.com/Schrodinger168/practice/-/tree/master#

Any help for this would be much appreciated!! Thank in advance!!

Comment: Have you tried using: scale_fill_manual()?

Comment: Yeah I tried but like I said it required me to fill 55 colors by myself

Comment: You don't if use rainbow(55)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are best preparing the data outside of the `ggplot` call while data wrangling.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

cv_states = read.csv("coronavirus_states.csv")

a <- cv_states %>%
  group_by(state) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(new_cases)) %>%
  mutate(pourcentage = total/sum(total)*100,
         state_pc = paste0(state, " (", round(pourcentage, 0), "%)")) 

ggplot(a,aes(x = fct_reorder(state, pourcentage), y = pourcentage, fill = state_pc))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 5))+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]